# Meaning of the phrase "caught-up" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have come across it in the 23rd episode of the 5th season of *Friends*. Here is the context:

> Joey: This is Vegas man! People will pay to see freaky stuff! Okay,
>   how much would you pay to see this hand (Holds up his left hand)
>   twice? Huh?
>
> Chandler: (Pause) Y'know, I-I can't really put a price on that Joe.
>
> Joey: Hey, are you unsupporting me again?
>
> Chandler: No! No! I support you 100%! I just didn't, I didn't get it
>   right away. Y'know now **I'm caught up**! Identical hand twins! It's a
>   million-dollar idea!

At first I thought he said *I caught on*, which after listening again and checking the transcripts he actually didn't. That would make sense to me as *catch on* means to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed used to mean "now I understand" in this case.  There are a bunch of metaphors that treat the learning or understanding process as a sort of journey, where one person is leading and the other is following.  For example, if Joey is telling Chandler something:

- Joey might say, "Are you **following me**?" which means, "are you understanding everything I say?"
- Chandler might say, "I'm **not following**," or even, "I'm **lost**," which means he is not understanding.
- Chandler might also say, "I **fell behind** for a while there, but now I'm **caught up**," which means he wasn't understanding at first, but now he is.